# Angular unable to populate mat-select control in a reactive form when its opened for edit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new to angular and i think i've wasted alot of time on a very simple step.

I have a very simple form that is used to create `Question` entity in database. Form appear to be working fine when creating a record. But when its opened to edit an existing record 'mat-selct' control fields are not being populated. These dropdowns are also being loaded from api.

Following is the code.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, inject, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Question } from 'src/app/Models/Question';
import { QuestionCategory } from 'src/app/Models/QuestionCategory';
import { QuestionType } from 'src/app/Models/QuestionType';
import { StResponse } from 'src/app/Models/StResponse';
import { QuestionCategoryService } from 'src/app/Services/question-category.service';
import { QuestionTypeService } from 'src/app/Services/question-type.service';
import { QuestionService } from 'src/app/Services/question.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-form',
  templateUrl: './question-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question-form.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionFormComponent implements OnInit {

  // model: Question;
  @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective)
  formDirective!: FormGroupDirective;
  questionForm!: FormGroup

  questionTypes: QuestionType[] = []
  questionCategories: QuestionCategory [] = [];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, 
              private _service: QuestionService,
              private _quesCategoryServ: QuestionCategoryService,
              private _quesTypeServ: QuestionTypeService,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: Question
              ) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('QF Oninit', this.data);
    this._quesCategoryServ.getAll().subscribe((sr:StResponse)=>{
      console.log('QesComp:', sr.data)
      this.questionCategories = sr.data.QuestionCategory;
    });
    this._quesTypeServ.getAll().subscribe((sr:StResponse)=>{
      console.log('QesComp:', sr.data)
      this.questionTypes = sr.data.QuestionType;
    });

    this.questionForm = this._fb.group({
      shortText: ['',Validators.required],
      text: ['',Validators.required],
      textInfo: [''],
      questionType: [null,Validators.required],
      questionCategory:[null,Validators.required],
    });

    if(this.data){
      console.log('oninit-forEdit')
      this.questionForm.patchValue({
        shortText: this.data.shortText,
        text: this.data.text,
        textInfo: this.data.textInfo,
        questionType: this.data.questionType,
        questionCategory: this.data.questionCategory,
      });

    }
  }

  onFormSubmit():void {
    if(this.questionForm.valid){
      console.log('submited form values',this.questionForm.value);
      this._service.add(this.questionForm.value).subscribe({
        next: (val: StResponse) => {
          alert('Question Added')
          // this.questionForm.reset();
          this.formDirective.resetForm();
          console.log('form resetted!')
        },
        error: (err: any) =>{
          console.error(err);
        }
      })
    }
  }
  
  // FormControl fields references for validation
  get shortText() { return this.questionForm.get('shortText'); }
  get text() { return this.questionForm.get('text'); }
  get textInfo() { return this.questionForm.get('textInfo'); }
  get questionType() { return this.questionForm.get('questionType'); }
  get questionCategory() { return this.questionForm.get('questionCategory'); }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Question</h1>
<form [formGroup]="questionForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <div mat-dialog-content class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Short Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Ex. Wheels." formControlName="shortText">
                <mat-error *ngIf="shortText?.invalid">Enter short text.</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Ex. Undamaged, All nuts tight." formControlName="text">
                <mat-error *ngIf="text?.invalid">Please enter question text.</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Details</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. Any details to further explain this question." formControlName="textInfo"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="questionType" >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let typeOption of questionTypes" [value]="typeOption"> 
                    {{typeOption.code}} 
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf="questionType?.invalid">You must make a selection</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="questionCategory" >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let categoryOption of questionCategories" [value]="categoryOption">
                    {{categoryOption.code}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf="questionCategory?.invalid">You must make a selection</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions class="action">
    <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
export class Question{
    id: number;
    shortText: string;
    text: string;
    textInfo: string;
    questionType: QuestionType;
    questionCategory: QuestionCategory;

    constructor(){
        this.id = 0;
        this.shortText = '';
        this.text = '';
        this.textInfo = '';
        this.questionType = new QuestionType();
        this.questionCategory = new QuestionCategory();
    }
}

export class QuestionType{
    id: number;
    code: string;

    constructor(){
        this.id = 0;
        this.code = '';
    }
}

export class QuestionCategory{
    id: number;
    code: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(){
        this.id = 0;
        this.code = '';
        this.name = '';
    }
}
```

**Some Additional findings**
Other inputs for shortText, text, TextInfo are being populate. Only Mat-select are not being loaded. I must be missin some thing silly as even the values for select are not populating, they are there as if i keep them blank when its opend for edit and just press save again. The values are being submitted and get persisted in DB.

I've also tried `form.setValue()` method but still no luck.

```
    // part of ngOnInit()

    if(this.data){
      console.log('oninit-forEdit')
      this.questionForm.patchValue({
        shortText: this.data.shortText,
        text: this.data.text,
        textInfo: this.data.textInfo,
        // questionType: this.data.questionType,
        // questionCategory: this.data.questionCategory,
      });

      const selectedCategory = this.questionCategories.find(category => category.id === this.data.questionCategory.id);
      const selectedType = this.questionTypes.find(type => type.id === this.data.questionType.id);


      this.questionForm.get('questionCategory')?.setValue(selectedCategory);
      this.questionForm.get('questionType')?.setValue(selectedType);
    }
  }
```

Any help or direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deciding which option to mark as selected, Angular compares values by identity (===).

This doesn't work when editing form, because current form control value is not equal to any of the values from the list, ie. **they are not the same objects** (even though they have the same structure).

`questionTypes` are retrieved by calling `this._quesTypeServ.getAll`, and current form control value is `data.questionType`.

To make Angular compare values in some other way, you can use `compareWith` input of `SelectControlValueAccessor`.

We can compare values by id, because that property is unique for each of these objects:

```
compareFn(a: QuestionType, b: QuestionType): boolean {
    return a && b ? (a.id === b.id) : (a === b);
}
```

And in template:

```
<mat-select formControlName="questionType" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let typeOption of questionTypes" [value]="typeOption"> 
        {{typeOption.code}} 
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Documentation about compareWith: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection

Comment: Thanks mate you are Spot on. It worked.
One more thing if you could direct me with. Although its working perfectly but still i'm getting this `Can't bind to 'compareWith' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.` error showing on VS code. And its not limited to this only. Few other attributes like `[formGroup]="questionForm"` on my <form> tag or `[value]="typeOption"` on my <mat-select> tag are showing on my html. I have imported the modules offcourse. Any idea why this abnormaly showing errors are coming from. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably missing some import. Have you imported ReactiveFormsModule? MatFormFieldModule? MatSelectModule? Try commenting out html of you component until it starts compiling. That will help you pinpoint which part of the template is causing compilation error. Or you can upload the code somewhere so I can take a look.

Comment: Ignore previous comment, it's not compilation errors, but VSCode errors only. Do you have Angular language service plugin installed? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Comment: Yes, and ive updated my angular to latest for this fresh project. After update i've been getting `Angular extension might not work correctly because ngcc operation failed. Try to invoke ngcc manually by running 'npm/yarn run ngcc'. Please see the extension output for more information.` I've tried resinstalling extension, changing its version to previous (Read somewhere to switch btw version). But still getting this popup everynow and then. Is there some settings file i need to fix maybe.

Comment: You are using Angular 16? Maybe you can try upgrading VSCode to latest version